# Google Maps With ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Map with React. But when I run my project, I get an error in Polygon.js file

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined

Please, let me know why?

This is snip code and image description for error:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { GoogleAPIWrapper, InfoWindow, Marker } from 'google-maps-react'


export class MapContainer extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadMap();
  }
  loadMap() {
    let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: { lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195 },
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeID: 'roadmap'
    })
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: "100%",
      hight: "100%"
    };
    return (
      <div id='map'>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleAPIWrapper(
  {
    apiKey: "MY_KEY",
  }
)(MapContainer);
```

[Error_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oSOk.png)

[Error_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmb4j.png)

Comment: is it `GoogleAPIWarapper` or `GoogleAPIWrapper` ? AND aren't you binding `loadMap()` in the constructor ?

Comment: Hi Dane ! Sr, I'm wrong type in GoogleAPIWarapper ( GoogleAPIWrapper). I have get new Error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function " at line : export default GoogleAPIWrapper(
  {
    apiKey: "MY_KEY"
  }
)(MapContainer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have some errors in your code, 
following the [docs](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react), you shouldn't be able to even export your component (typo in 'GoogleAPIWarapper').

## working example

```
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';
import React, { Component} from 'react';
export class MapContainer extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}>
      <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
            name={'Current location'} />
      <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
       <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
       </div>
      </InfoWindow>
  </Map>
 );
 }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'apiKey'
})(MapContainer)
```

Comment: Tks . My project working, it's my fault. Because I don't understand how ways it's activity.